# Null-coalescing operator ?? vs. ??= in C#

Tags: c#

Is use of ?? when checking a null using null-coalescing operator and there is ??= in C# 8.0. There is the same functionality behavior and what is the advantage of using ==? operator.

```
int? a = null;   
int b = 10;    
a = a ??= 0;
a = a ?? b;
```

Comment: They're simply different things. It's like asking if using `+` is bad practice when we have `+=`.

Comment: Why would it be a bad practice? Can you explain what you're concerned about instead? Your last line won't compile anyway. Do you mean `a = a ?? b`?

Comment: You mean "is `a = a ?? 0` considered bad practice when you can use `a ??= 0`?"?

Comment: @JeroenMostert, Sweeper, CodeCaster Thanks for your response. I modified question. I wanted to ask that same functionality therefore what is the benefit of using (==?) this operator.

Comment: The analogy still works: it's like asking why anyone would use `i += 5` when they could also write `i = i + 5`, and it has the same answer -- it saves keystrokes for a common case. (And it becomes obvious to have the `??=` operator when there's the `??` operator, given that most existing operators have an `=` form.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is "bad practice" is highly opinionated, but in this case, not really.

The new operator `??=` only replaces the common case of `a = a ?? b`.

There are still many other users for `??`, e.g. `if (a?.Foo() ?? false)` or `Foo(a ?? 0)` or `var c = a ?? b` etc.